# Kubernetes CronJob Pod status remains Running

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-cronjob

I want to run a Kubernetes CronJob for a PHP script. Job executes properly but status of the POD remains running and after few minutes it becomes Error. It should be Completed status. Tried with different options but couldn't be able to resolve the issue.

**Here is my CronJob Yaml file**

[image]

**Here is the output of kubectl get pods**
[image]

**Here is the log output inside the container.**

Ignore the PHP exception. Issue is there regardless of the exception.

[image]

Comment: what do you see in `kubectl describe pod <pod_name>` ? (of one of the errors)

Comment: exit code `0` makes a pod completed status, exit code `1` makes it set status as Error. make sure its not getting any exception or exit code `1`.

Comment: You seem to have attached an image instead of your YAML file, and images instead of the plain-text `kubectl` outputs.  Can you replace these images with the actual text contents?  (I can't `kubectl apply -f` a PNG file.)

Comment: Thanks all for your help. I was able to resolve the issue. As mentioned by @SaikatChakrabortty it was due to exit code of the PHP application.

Comment: @SaikatChakrabortt would you consider converting your comment into an answer?

Comment: @thomas sure, thank you, I have added just now!

Answer (score 6):

The state of the pod sets to completed when the running process / the application or the container returns exit code `0`.

If in case it's returning a **non-zero** exit code it usually sets it to state `Error`.

If you want the pod set to completed status, just make sure the application at the end returning an exit code which is `0`.

**OPINION:  It's something which is usual cases should be/are handled by the application itself.**

I'm attaching [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/) for the k8s jobs.